# Header with centered text and button aligned to the right

Tags: html, css

I want to have a header on my website with some text which is centred in the page. There should be a button on the same height/line which is aligned to the right.

This is what I've got currently:
[image: current appearance]

And this is defined like this:

```html
<header>
    <h1>Please Center Me</h1>
    <span class="material-icons">search</span>
</header>
```

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #1DA87F;
    color: #EBEF8E;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: flex;
}

header h1 {
    margin: auto;
    align-self: center;
}

.material-icons {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: auto;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

As you can see, the "Please Center Me" text is not really centered, it's being off-set by the `search` text (icon).

Comment: Change span do div, style="float: right", text will be centered in header.

Comment: @Grumpy Could you share an example where that works? I've tried using floats but it pushes the search icon below the text, rather than being on the same horizonal alignment.

Comment: Does something like this works for you? https://jsfiddle.net/sinisa92/xuzjptb1/ this is using `flex-grow`